# I have Windows Vista, and I think I have a virus; what do I do?

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Has anyone ever seen a file named "xp proxy" followed by a series of numbers? It keeps attempting to download itself to my computer.

Comment: Are you visiting a certain website when it is trying or is it just a constant thing?

Comment: Add useful informations!
When it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the order given below to disinfect your PC

1.) On a PC that is Not infected, Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc on the Infected PC and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more information would assist.  Are the numbers an IP address or just numbers. What are you doing when this happens?  Connecting to a web page or?

Do you have antivirus software on the system?  Is it up to date?

Malwarebytes [Main page](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) AdAware [Main Page](http://www.lavasoft.com/) and Spybot [Download](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/download/index.html) can all assist in scanning